# Does zsh use canonical-mode for the terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, readline

I have been exploring `terminfo` and `stty`.
If I run `stty -a|grep icanon` it appears that canonical mode is set, but if I try to turn it off with `stty -icanon` and check again, I see that it is still set.
When I do the same thing under bash, I am able to disable icanon, but I don't notice any change in behaviour.
So I have 2 questions; why am I unable to disable icanon in zsh, and how should it affect the behaviour if I could?

Answer (score 7):

> When I do the same thing under bash, I am able to disable icanon, but I don't notice any change in behaviour.

That's because bash turns the canonical mode *off* when reading commands from the user (in order to be able to implement line editing features not offered by the terminal driver -- like inserting text, moving the cursor left and right with the arrow keys, etc), and then *restores* the previous terminal settings upon running any command line.

To see its effect, run an external command like `cat`:

```
bash$ stty -icanon
bash$ cat
hheelloo
```

Each key will be repeated, once because `stty echo` is on, and once because `cat` will immediately read it and write it back, instead of having to wait for complete lines.

> [with zsh] if I try to turn it off with `stty -icanon` and check again, I see that it is still set.

When restoring the previous terminal settings as described above, `zsh` is also enforcing [some sane defaults](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/59a451abae442892e35b13844a612c7723ce699c/Src/Zle/zle_main.c#L227) (which include the `echo` and `icanon` settings). Probably that's because it assumes that, if a command left the canonical mode *off* upon terminating, it was just an accident (e.g. as when a full screen app like `vi` or `less` crashed).

I wasn't able to find any `zsh` option which would make it work like `bash` (and like any other program using the readline library), but if you want to turn the icanon mode off before running a command, you can do it by calling stty from the same command line:

```
zsh$ stty -icanon; cat
hheelloo
```

Comment: *"Probably that's because it assumes that, if a command left the canonical mode off upon terminating, it was just an accident"*. Yes, zsh has been setting ICANON and ECHO to ["sanitize the tty"](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/59a451abae442892e35b13844a612c7723ce699c/Src/Zle/zle_main.c#L225) (but otherwise leaving alone the other settings as set by the user) since around 1994 (2.4 or about).

Comment: The thing that this answer could state more clearly is that line editors like ZLE, editline, and GNU Readline switch the line discipline into a different mode for much the same reason as `vi` et al. do, and this is what pretty much _anything_ with a line editor will do, from shells to `bc`.  So this is why there's no apparent change in behaviour.  Quite a number of programs aren't using "cooked" input.

Comment: OK, so just to clarify; both zsh & bash run the line editor with icanon off, but when I run the stty command they temporarily turn icanon on before stty prints its output, unless it was already explicitly turned off in bash. Furthermore, it's not possible to turn icanon on for line editing in either zsh or bash, since this would disable some of the extra line editing commands that they provide. Correct?